# How can Heroku:cron handle a range of hours?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, heroku

I have a cron job on Heroku that needs to run for 8 hours a day.  (Once an hour, eight times, each day.).

These do work as expected:
(all code in /lib/tasks/cron.rake)

```
if Time.now.hour == 6
  puts "Ok it's 6am and I printed"
  puts "6:00 PST put is done."
end

if Time.now.hour == 7
  puts "Ok it's 7am and I printed"
  puts "7:00 PST put is done."
end

if Time.now.hour == 8
  puts "I printed at 8am"
  puts "8:00 PST put is done."
end

if Time.now.hour == 9
  puts "9:00 PST open put"
  puts "9:00 PST put is done."
end
```

---

This code, however, doesn't work:

```
if Time.now.hour (6..14)
  puts "I did the rake job"
end
```

I've also tried the following variants.  Didn't work.
    if Time.now.hour == (6..14)
    if Time.now.hour = (6..14)
    if Time.now.hour == 6..14
    if Time.now.hour = 6..14

Anyone know how I can put a range in a Heroku cron job?  Listing lots of jobs by hour just seems wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to see if that range includes the hour:

```
if (6..14).include?(Time.now.hour) 
  puts "I did the rake job"
end
```

Comment: Though I +1'd both, I prefer this syntax to the `===` since it's easier to understand on first look.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is

```
if (6..14) === Time.now.hour
  # Run command
end
```

Comment: To be clear: this works because `Time.now.hour == (6..14)` checks if the current hour is equal to a range, which can never be true. However, a range object has a special method named `===` which in this case is *not* an equality check, but an inclusion check.